# XSLT default variable value if value not present

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to declare a variable that has a default value or if a value is present in a repeating set to use a new different value.

This is what I have so far.

```
      <xsl:variable name="lsind">
        <xsl:value-of select="'N'"/>

        <xsl:for-each select='./Plan/InvestmentStrategy/FundSplit'>
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains(./@FundName, 'Lifestyle')">
              <xsl:value-of select="'Y'"/>
            </xsl:when>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:variable>
```

What I want is if any instances of ./Plan/InvestmentStrategy/FundSplit/@FundName 'contains' LifeStyle then lsind ' Y' otherwise it falls back to the default value of 'N'.

I am doing it this way as if i use 'otherwise the last occurrence could potentially set lsind back to N?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
<xsl:variable name="lsind">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="Plan/InvestmentStrategy/FundSplit[contains(@FundName, 'Lifestyle')]">
       <xsl:text>Y</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
       <xsl:text>N</xsl:text>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

should suffice

Comment: You are a beautiful human being. Thank you! I was just starting to explore the xpath route suspecting that there must be a way.

Answer (score 6):

**This can be specified in a single XPath expression** (even in XPath 1.0):

```
 <xsl:variable name="vLsind" select=
 "substring('YN',
             2 - boolean(plan/InvestmentStrategy/FundSplit[@FundName='Lifestyle']),
             1)"/>
```

**Example 1**:

```
<plan>
 <InvestmentStrategy>
  <FundSplit FundName="Lifestyle"/>
 </InvestmentStrategy>
</plan>
```

**Transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vLsind" select=
 "substring('YN',
             2 - boolean(plan/InvestmentStrategy/FundSplit[@FundName='Lifestyle']),
             1)"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:value-of select="$vLsind"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**:

```
Y
```

**Example 2**:

```
<plan>
 <InvestmentStrategy>
  <FundSplit FundName="No Lifestyle"/>
 </InvestmentStrategy>
</plan>
```

**Result**:

```
N
```

**Explanation**:

1. By definition `boolean(some-node-set)` is `true()` exactly when `some-node-set` is non-empty.
2. By definition `number(true())` is `1` and `number(false())` is `0`
3. 1 and 2 cobined gives us: `number(boolean(some-node-set))` is `1` exactly when `some-node-set` is non-empty, otherwise it is `0`.

**Other single-expression solutions**:

**XPath 1.0**:

```
translate(number(boolean(YourXPathExpression)), '10', 'YN')
```

**XPath 2.0**:

```
if(YourXPathExpression)
 then 'Y'
 else 'N'
```

**Or even**:

```
 ('N', 'Y')[number(boolean(YourXPathExpression)) +1]
```

Comment: +1 Those are some wonderful examples of (mis)using XPath 1.0 functions!

Comment: @Goran: Was this stated by the police department? If *this* is misuse, then I am in for a much bigger trouble... :)

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev. It is not misuse, but it can be very obtuse, because it masks a logical construct within an expression, which may not be good for long-term maintenance, as most, or whomever comes after them, may need to try to get their head around it every time they re-visit it.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev. Unfortunately, the designers of XSL made it very wordy, such as using *otherwise* when *else* would have been fine. These are text files, and lots of extra characters add up to extra load times from disk. Not a worry on a small file, but large files, in conjunction with scale, can limit performance.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev. I don't know why the designers of XML didn't reserve all the single character namespaces for core XML technologies, such as *x* instead of *xsl*. Since all my usage of XML for data doesn't use namespaces, I define *xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">* as *xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">* instead, so that all my XSL tags begin with *<x:* instead of  *<xsl:*. Saves a lot of typing time.

Comment: @Patanjali, The only reserved namespace prefixes are: "xml" and "xmlns" -- I believe this was done in order not to have a lot of "forbidden prefixes" . XQuery also pre-defines the prefix "xs" for the XML Schema Namespace. As for using an abbreviated prefix for the XSLT namespace, this could affect some XSLT IDEs that are hardwired to only understand "xsl:"

Comment: @Patanjali: Re: "whomever comes after them, may need to try to get their head around it every time they re-visit it."  Trying to "get one's head around" a new idea is actually a good thing :)

Comment: @Patanjali: Re: "Unfortunately, the designers of XSL made it very wordy"  -- this is actually a good thing  -- makes the code more readable and error-prone to typos that make a valid syntactic token of the language into another valid syntactic token. Nobody (since year 2000) else has complained about XSLT being "wordy" -- most people use XSLT IDEs, which have intellisense prompts and autocompletion, thus the programmer never writes whole XSLT tokens -- just clicks a few keys.

Comment: A person than can explain this much better than me, is of course Dr. Michael Kay ( @michael-kay )

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev. There is a difference between an *institutional* and an obtuse *incidental* 'new'. The former can be interesting as its a new frontier, but the latter can be a real PITA because it inopportunely crops up when trying to solve a bigger problem, resulting in not having the time to enthusiastically indulge oneself in something new! ;-(

Comment: Dear @Patanjali, Sorry, I don't understand what you are saying in your last comment. Nobody is forcing anyone to like and/or use XSLT if they don't like it. There are many things I don't like but I don't consider this fact to be a significant reason to write comments expressing my feelings. I would never express dissatisfaction with a language that I don't understand sufficiently. Often, by gaining understanding one starts liking a new language or a new area. I can definitely affirm that lexical "issues" are non-essential for the power, elegance ease of use and adoption of XSLT.

Comment: @Patanjali, And BTW, this answer is a complete XPATH solution, but the last 5 comments, four of which you wrote within a single hour, are about some lexical aspects of XSLT... Maybe it would be preferable to write comments that are more relevant to the answer they are attached to?

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev. Are you the police now? On one hand you claim the right to be *flexible* with your use of XSLT, but rail against others doing that. Fair suck of the sap!

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev. Yes, *institutional* et al, was a bit obtuse. Learning to use advanced functionality can be a beneficial challenge, but that coming across unconventional usage when you are trying to debug code down the track can be a distracting mental exercise. Of course, you can use whatever you want, but my warning was much like yours about not using *xsl:*: what you do may not work well with other people or tools. While I like those single-expressions, I know that I would probably get confused if I had to revisit them in 6 months time.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev. I like XSLT, and have used it on various projects for over 15 years, but, in my opinion, that does not mean that it is *perfect*. However, I agree that my expression of that here might have triggered an excessive distraction from this thread.

Comment: @Patanjali, Thank you for the very interesting thoughts. I am sure that if we meet in the future we'll enjoy talking more on these topics. You are right that most of the things I have been writing about in my blog, taken in isolation may seem strange. While I am proud that I have produced all them as a whole, and they determine to a large extent who I am, I have yet to discover what the *next phase* should be. Please, contact me via email should you have any ideas.